# ADC signal long trace voltage drop compensation using amp and return trace

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, signal, signal-integrity

I'm running a signal for an ADC a pretty good distance and through a connector.  The voltage drops are not unsubstantial.

The concept is to run an identical return trace and compare the post-loss voltage to the orignal output voltage right at the source. That goes through a fully differential amp, boosting the signal so that the halfway point is exactly what originaly came out of the source amp.

Is this common?  Is there a better way to do it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flXsE8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Consider all impedances, and spectrum , look at Active Guarding and buffering source signal, balanced  and CM signals, noise.

Comment: Voltage drop would imply a current.

Comment: @SimonRichter Good point, there is low current here though, 250Kohm ADC impedence is 20uA at 4V is a 13uV drop on a 10" 7mil trace, that is like 7-8 LSBs on a 24 bit ADC

Comment: You're worrying about 13uV on a 4V signal..? That is 0.000325% error? It's also way smaller than some of the other offsets and errors in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sort of remote sensing is usually used for transmitting power over long cables, not for signals.

Signals should be received with a high impedance inputs so that the current is small enough in the wires that resistive losses are trivial.

If you are transmitting over a long distance, it is also prudent to add buffers/drivers to the sending end to transmit a differential signal from a low impedance output. Or perhaps using a current loop of some sort. Or better still, digitize it remotely.

Comment: Buffers look to be the answer.  I found a model with 10Tohm impedence.